# How to Declare an Array of Generic Dictionaries in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I want to create an array of Dictionaries. But the array size is unknown. For integer, i used List to obtain the integer array of unknown size. But in the case of Dictionary, am not able to create a list of Dictionary. Is thr any wayz by which this can be done? 
`Dictionary(int, String) paramList=null;`
I am want to create the array of paramList(above). I am using C Sharp.

Comment: The above code isn't valid C#. I assume you meant to use `<...>` instead of `(...)`. Also, I don't understand the question; it looks like you want a `List<Dictionary<int, string>>`; is that the case?

Comment: ya i wanted to use < >.. and i also used List<Dictionary<int,String>> and it is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Dictionary<int, String>> paramList = new List<Dictionary<int, String>>();
```

However, this is usually not the right data structure.  More likely, you just need a single dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, String> paramList = new Dictionary<int, String>();
paramList[1] = "foo";
paramList[2] = "bar";
```